# Mobile keyword Unsubscribe with landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud

is it possible to unsubscribe a contact from a keyword with an automation or API script (the customer can unsubsribe from a specific mobile communication with a landing page)?

Comment: I believe what you might be searching for is the soap method [UnsubEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubevent.htm)

Comment: Thank you, but how can i use it to unsubscribe only from a list atached to a keyword(Promo...), is ther an exemple of using this method?

Comment: you need to unsubscribe the contact from particular list using api ?

Answer (score 2):

Keyword-level opt-outs are only available in Australia for the moment https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_sms_keyword_opt_out.htm&type=5

Here is how you can implement a keyword-level subscription model in Marketing Cloud.

**Contact Builder**

1. Create a Data Extension called `SMS Keyword Optins` with these fields : `ContactKey (Text) / Keyword1 (Boolean) / Keyword2 (Boolean) / Keyword3 (Boolean) / ...`
2. Link this Data Extension to the population in Data Designer
3. Initiliaze this Data Extension for all your customers

**Cloud Pages**

4. Create a Custom Preference Center (global opt-in checkbox / keyword1 opt-in checkbox / keyword2 opt-in checkbox / ... ) and pre-fill the checkboxes using `Lookuprows()` Function
5. Feed this Data Extension with opt-in/outs when the customer submits the form using AMPScript `UpdateDE()` function

**Mobile Connect**

6. Create Exclusion Lists in MobileConnect for every Keyword = False
7. Make sure to select the appropriate Keyword Exclusion List in every MobileConnect Send

**Journey Builder**

8. Make sure to exclude Customers with a decision split before any Send SMS activity by selecting the right Keyword = False

**Dealing with STOP Keyword**

9. Within the STOP response SMS, use `UpdateDE()` function to set all values in `SMS Keyword Optins` DE to False when a Customer sends the "STOP" keyword

Comment: All correct, but fyi keyword level Opt-Out in MobileConnect is available for Australia. Here is an article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_sms_keyword_opt_out.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes you’re right ! I forgot to mention it. I will update my answer to include this information.

Comment: Hi Zreljazouli, thank you for your answer, have you an exemple of script for the stop keyword. i have to use the updateDe function but when i send the stop sms where can i retrieve this data in SFMC? is there ay default DE?